# How to get process id of process that is triggered by a powershell script

Tags: powershell, pid, windows-update

I have a script that has been executed using powershell ISE.
This Invoke-WUInstall seems to trigger powershell.exe.
How can I capture the process ID for the powershell.exe.

```
$WUInstallScript = { Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll |Out-File C:\SUPPORT\text.log}
Invoke-WUInstall -ComputerName computername -Script $WUInstallScript -Confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it to the log file, and pick it up from there:

```
$WUInstallScript = { "Process ID is $PID" | Out-File C:\SUPPORT\text.log
                     Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll | Out-File C:\SUPPORT\text.log -Append}
Invoke-WUInstall -ComputerName computername -Script $WUInstallScript -Confirm:$false
```